# Why does my decipher.final fail given an incorrect key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

**Problem and App BG:** So I'm creating a nodeJS application which stores some sensitive data, and I would like to encrypt everything. But when I try to decrypt some data with the wrong key, I get a TypeError: DecipherFinal fail error.

Here is how my application's security works: (Note that this is for AppJS and NOT a web-facing application)

1. User can 'create account', which creates a new file; The first line of the file serves as an identifier: encrypt("Somestring" + username)
2. User can login, which opens up the file and decrypts the first line using their password. If it happens to be "Somestring" + username, then we log the user in.

This is working just fine as long as I don't use the wrong key, which results in the DecipherFinal fail error.

**Questions:**

1. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do? I assumed that if I ran the data through the decryption function with an incorrect key, I would just get incorrect data.
2. Is this a bad design? I read somewhere that you shouldn't store a hashed password in the same database as the data encrypted with that password, so instead of storing a password at all I figured the user could just keep track of it, and they could decrypt an expected message for authorization. The nature of the data is such that it's VERY important that nobody else gets their hands on it, but NOT VERY important that the user can recover their data.
3. Is this "rolling my own crypto"? Does that mean sticking to known patterns or just sticking to proven primitives and algorithms? If this is rolling my own, are there any implementations of an encrypted container I could use for Node?

**Code:**

https://gist.github.com/sanarothe/5993384

Thanks a lot,

Cameron

Comment: What gains does this approach offer over the traditional "store the hash" one? You'll have to run the password through a key-derivation function like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why decryption failed, AES256 has a 16 byte block size (ie, it can only encrypt data in even 16 byte blocks) Since your data isn't necessarily a size that is divisible by 16, the crypto library has [autopadding](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true) turned on to add some filler data (PKCS in this case) to make the length divisible by 16.

The padding is constructed so that when decryption gets to the end of the data, it knows exactly what bytes to remove to cut the message off at the right byte and not return junk at the end. The problem is that when it ends with random data, the "unpadding" detects that it cannot find the end marker and fails decryption. Note that totally random data may actually contain a valid marker, so you're not in any way guaranteed that this check will fail even on random data.

If you really don't want decryption to fail on a padding mismatch, you can ensure that your data's length is divisible by 16 (by padding it yourself in whatever way you like) and turn off autopadding using [`cipher.setautopadding(false)`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true) before calling `final` on both encryption and decryption. That way, you won't get decryption failures, and will, as you're trying, have to detect crypto failures yourself.

As for design, to me the whole scheme sounds a bit like rolling your own security. For example, if you add data that can be checked for validity (as you do with the first row of known data), you're helping attackers by allowing them to work with a (more or less) known plain text at a known location in the stream to test keys. AES256 is fairly secure against known plain text attacks for now, but you never know in a few years.

A second thing, you'll want to use AES-256-CBC or similar, I'm unsure what [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) the crypto modure uses by default.

Comment: AES always has a block size of 16 bytes. AES-256 uses a _key_ size of 32 bytes.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Ah, yes, mixed it up with Rijndael which (is free to) use 256 bits block size. Fixed the answer.

Comment: I'm with you regarding the default mode of operation. Never rely on the default; it makes your code more obscure at the minimum. If it defaults to e.g. ECB you are in trouble. I doubt anybody will be brute forcing AES after a few years. It would mean that there are bigger things to worry about; any symmetrical cipher is probably broken if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it clarified a lot. I had kind of suspected that leaving that known data at the beginning of the container for verification might be an issue. (Ever since reading about breaking DVD CSS)

Anyway, thanks again, I will re-think my approach. (After some research...)